# How to define "boxes" on a picture and fill them with text?

Tags: php, image-processing, text-processing

I have predefined print samples provided by an insurance company.  They do not accept prints in any other format.  I have to write an app that should be able to fill in those forms/samples.

I have decided to scan samples and fill them with some image library, and here is my problem ;)

The data to fill in forms is often too "large" to fit into "fill box".  I would like to automatically determine the size of the font used to fit the data into the box, or even break data in two or more lines.

My questions:

- Is there any image library that will be able to do this or do I have to write all that logic from scratch?
- Maybe I have to solve this problem in other way?

Comment: Have you thought about converting to a PDF and using template fields? There are plenty of drivers out there that can write PDFs with place-holders that can format based on the size of the placeholder.

Comment: Yeah I have thought about this, but lots of this forms are advanced tabular lay-outed formats, and I don't know any simple way to convert it to nice PDFs?

Comment: @canni, Adobe Acrobat is well-suited to this kind of work.  You'll have much better luck with this method, than hacking something together with PHP.

Comment: @Brad my data comes from PHP app, and mix php app with acrobat I think isn't best solution

Comment: http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple answer: yes, you should write this logic from scratch. I understand your reluctance to deal with PDF. Most libraries that do any kind of text rendering, including the PHP GD library using FreeType, will provide a method to find the bounding-box size of a text string before you render it. In PHP, it is `imageftbbox` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageftbbox.php. You can use this to at the very least guess and check your way to the right font size for a given area.